# ftp_put() [<a href='function.ftp-put'>function.ftp-put</a>]: Ok to send data

Tags: php

I wrote a FTP app that uploads files to a remote server with PHP FTP's functionality. However I constantly get the following error `ftp_put() [<a href='function.ftp-put'>function.ftp-put</a>]: Ok to send data.` and have no idea what this means.

This is how the line looks where I'm getting the error `ftp_put($connection, $main_dir.'/class.phpmailer.php','class.phpmailer.php', FTP_ASCII)`

I even CHMOD the class.phpmailer.php file to 777 `-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache 74526 Feb 11 12:16 class.phpmailer.php` and still nothing, I do not know why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to switch to passive mode ftp_pasv() after you login, but before you upload. If it doesn't help, put more code here (connect, login, etc.)

Comment: I'm tried this, it somehow works now, but will be for sure at the end of the day, after some testing etc